# How can I get the list of selected values in an excel ListBox object using xlwings?

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

I'm trying to know which items of my excel ListBox is being selected using xlwings.

What works:

```
sheet = xw.sheets.active
sheet.api.Shapes('ListBox11').ControlFormat.ListCount
#returns 17 because 17 items in my ListBox
```

What I tried and fails with error (com_error: (-2147352570, 'Unknown name.', None, None)) :

```
sheet.api.Shapes('ListBox11').ControlFormat.SelectedValue
#or
sheet.api.Shapes('ListBox11').ControlFormat.List
#or
sheet.api.Shapes('ListBox11').ControlFormat.Selected(0)
```

Can't manage to figure it out. Help would be much appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following;
This code is using an Active X Listbox

```
...
sheet = xw.sheets.active

lb_obj = sheet.api.OLEObjects("ListBox11").Object
list_count = lb_obj.ListCount

for x in range(list_count):
    if lb_obj.Selected(x) == True:
        print(lb_obj.List[x])
```